# PHP F3 find escaping limit and offset conditions

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I was introduced to the PHP Fat Free Framework yesterday and I am now exploring its possibilities for my REST api. I am now trying to do a select query with limit and offset parameters. Following its documentation, I came up with the following:

```
$query = array('userid=?', F3::get('userid'));
$extra = array(
    'order'     =>'id DESC',
    'offset'    => isset($_GET['offset']) ? (int)$_GET['offset'] : 0,
    'limit'     => isset($_GET['limit']) ? (int)$_GET['limit'] : 5
);
$list = $this->mapper->find($query, $extra);
```

However, while I was under the impression that F3 would handle the escaping, it doesn't. Am I using the framework in the wrong way, or how should I handle the escaping here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `find()` you should use `paginate()` like this:

```
$list = $this->mapper->paginate(2, 5, array('userid=?', F3::get('userid')));
```

Check out the docs, it's quite easy to use. The result is different than `find()`, though, since it contains more info. The items returned will be in $list['subset']. You can do a var_dump of $list to see the other fields returned.